# Assign currently logged in user as default value for a model field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is my code

**models.py**

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    category=models.CharField(verbose_name=u"Category:", choices=cat, default=0, max_length=50)
    description=models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Description:', max_length=50)
    cost=models.DecimalField(verbose_name=u'Cost:', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    createdBy=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date']
```

**admin.py**

```
class ExpenseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('category', 'description', 'cost', 'date', 'createdBy')
    list_filter=('category', 'description', 'date')
    search_fields=('category', 'description', 'date')
    fieldsets = [
        (None, { 'fields': [('category', 'description', 'cost')] } ),
    ]
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if getattr(obj, 'createdBy', None) is None:
            obj.createdBy = request.user
        obj.save()
```

**views.py**

```
def newExpense(request):
    form=ExpenseForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        return redirect(monthExpense)
    context={
    'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'newExpense.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ExpenseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields=['category', 'description', 'cost']
```

In django admin site works fine but in my HTML site doesn't work.

**Displays an error:**

> IntegrityError at /newExpense/
>
> NOT NULL constraint failed: expense_expense.createdBy_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not included the `createdBy` field in your form - quite reasonably, as it should automatically be the user who's filling it out. So you have to fill it manually. Try the following change to your view function - this code:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

should become:

```
if form.is_valid():
    expense = form.save(commit = False)
    expense.createdBy = request.user
    expense.save()
```

To briefly explain, the `commit = False` stops the new model instance being automatically saved in the database (when it's saved as is, it violates the NOT NULL constraint and therefore throws the error you're seeing), but returns the `Expense` object that would be saved. This allows you to manually add the necessary `createdBy` property and then save it.